# How to create listbox like github

Tags: javascript, css, listbox, dropdown

I want to detect @ symbol (when typed inside a textarea) and open a dropdown with a list of users like Github ( check screenshot -> https://prnt.sc/220pwx9 ) using pure js

Is there any plugin available or any HTML, CSS, and JS code that would give me a workaround?

Comment: https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

Comment: @vee thanks for your reply that repository is helpful but I have one issue it does not automatically pop up when I type @ symbol. After typing @ keyword I have to write the first letter of any word can you help me to fix that

Comment: The document is on that page. Maybe use `enabled: 0` in the option. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: @vee thanks it worked why don't you add your comment as answer